# Спам в wordpress contact form

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

Каким образом можно организовать защиту от спама в wp при наличии плагина contact form 7. Почитав кучу информации понял что необходимо ставить плагины по защите от спама, но плагины по большей части платные. Второй способ который я нашел это добавления скрытого поля типа email (для примера), и затем его проверять на пустоту (человек не увидит его, бот заполнит) - насколько это действенный способ и как его реализовать подскажет кто нибудь?

Comment: а каптчу там нельзя добавить?

Comment: Предложение было, но сказали это в самом крайнем случае. Не хотят увеличивать нагрузку на пользователя. Еще есть какие то варианты?

Comment: я сделал кнопку "отправить сообщение", по нажатии на которую делаю форму visible и меняю action c localhost на реальный. и всё

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, т.к. я использую CF 7 я не могу влиять на первичное отражение в action значения, оно автоматом подставляет. А если убирать после его во время загрузки, то этот метод мне кажется не действенным из за того что спам-боты не ждут загрузки стилей, скриптов и тд, а при нахождении форм в верстке сразу же шлют (в некоторых случаях обходя клик по кнопке)

Comment: про это я не знаю :( не пользую ворд пресс

Comment: Какая нагрузка? Я же дал вам ответ - невидимая рекапча не создает никакой нагрузки на пользователя. И непробиваема, потому что это сервис Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой и действенный способ - поставьте плагин [Invisible reCaptcha for WordPress](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/invisible-recaptcha/).

Comment: Я Вас понял, но и Вы поймите. Я просто баработчик, все хотелки на стороне заказчика и он не хочет дополнительные манипуляции (здесь ведь нужно нажать и подождать). Решил проблему (надеюсь решил) установкой плагина Contact Form 7 Honeypot. Он добавляет поле в форму, которое по дефолту не заполнено имеет тип emeil (или другой какой зададите) и скрыто от глаз пользователя. Как писал выше в теории бот заполнит, а человек нет.

Comment: Я вам в десятый раз говорю - ничего нажимать и подождать не надо. Вы хоть удосужьтесь прочитать, что такое **invisible** recaptcha

Comment: Так сказать "удвою" этот ответ. Invisible reCaptcha действительно наиболее подходящее решение исходя из задачи. 
[Статья на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/320664/)

Comment: Прочел кучу материала по поводу установки данной recaptcha. везде описан метод, что необходимо вызвать callback функцию в которой указать `document.querySelector( '.wpcf7 form' ).submit();`. Но в таком случае происходит перезагрузка страницы и подстановка id формы в url адрес. Как избежать этого?

Comment: Не изобретать велосипед, а установить плагин, который я указал. Он прекрасно интегрирован с Contact Form 7.

Comment: Давай-те по порядку (простите за тупость). Установил как раз плагин что вы указали. Вписал все ключи, которые предоставляются сервисом данным для сайта конкретного. поставил везде где нужно галочки. Все работает, но при этом все сообщения помечаются как спам и не уходят

Comment: Что значит - помечаются как спам и НЕ УХОДЯТ? Где же они помечаются как спам?

Comment: В CF7 есть "зарезервированный" список уведомлений при отправке формы. При активации плагина отправка формы не происходит, выходит уведомление "Отправляемые данные определены как спам".

Comment: Никогда такого не видел. У меня этот плагин с CF7 установлен на ряде сайтов, все нормально

Answer (score 1):

> Каким образом можно организовать защиту от спама в wp при наличии
>   плагина contact form 7

Использовать встроенный механизм "вопрос-ответ". Только вопросы придумать уникальные, а не "третья планета от Солнца".